# Export Source Code with History from TFS 2010 as a manual export

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010, tfs

My developers and I are looking to move off TFS 2010, and what we are looking to do is export all the source code with history. The source code and history we want to export over to another network where we are standing up a Git Repository.

Every where I look gives examples of where TFS and Git have access to one another, but unfortunately, in our case the two networks are isolated from one another.

Is there away where I can simply export the data, transfer the data on to the new network and then import into Git?

Comment: can you move the code physically to the other network?

Comment: You can upgrade TFS to a modern version and use the support for Git repos that has existed since 2013.

Comment: Yes, we can physically copy the code from a local copy on a development desktop to the other network.

Comment: No we don't want to use TFS anymore as other projects at my company are using Git and the decision has been made that everyone is to use Git. Further the network we are on is being pensioned off and we need to be on a new network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Install [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) on your TFS 2010 server/any PC in your first netowrk with access to TFS (you also need [git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) installed).
- Migrate you TFVC code to a git repository:

  `git tfs clone https://{tfsServer}:8080/tfs/Collection $/project/repo . --branches=all`

Now you have a local git repo with your TFVC source code in your first network.

- Move this local git repo to the second network physically.
- Upload the code to your existing central git repository or create a new git repository and push the current code.

Comment: Is there another way without the need to install git on the first domain. It feels like a lot of work. Doesn't TFS allow you to export history and source code as a set of files?

Comment: Export to what? if you want to move the code to Git you must migrate the tfs (tfvc) to git, and for that you must git..

Comment: All I want is to copy all the source code along with the history which I can copy across to the new domain. The copying will have to be done as a manual process as they are not linked. Therefore, there is NO RDS or MSTSC

Comment: But now your code is in TFVC and in the new domain you use GIT, no?

Comment: This is the solution. Go and do it. Installing git windows msi is a 5 min easy task... There is no other magic "I just copy" solution. Migrate away of TFVC is a difficult task that even Microsoft didn't try to solve. Git-tfs is your best (but far from perfect) option. (signed by git-tfs main developer).